# mark processed JSON files in forkJoin

Tags: angular5

while there are certain pieces of code missing, the core logic is that a JSON file should be marked as 'processed' and not be processed again. If a call to assets/b.json is done, I need to cache that the file was visited before and hence, no second http call should be made to the same file. Right now, a file is called multiple times. Each JSON has a path identification:

```js
let touchedJSONFiles = {}

private setJSONAsTouched(path) {
  this.touchedJSONFiles[path]= true;
}

processJSONFiles() {
  // do some logic to build the JSON files that needs to be checked
  let files = [];//contains paths only such as abc/abc.json, 34.json
  let urls = [];// which urls to process, if any

  files.map(file => {
    if (this.touchedJSONFiles[file] == undefined) {
      urls.push(file);
    }
  });

  // do we have files to process?
    if (urls.length > 0 ) {
      forkJoin(urls).subscribe(results => {
        const len = urls.length;
        for(let k=0; k < len; k++) {
          this.setJSONAsTouched(files[k]);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Given the method could be called from wherever, I want to make it as reusable as possible. The current issue I am having is that a JSON file is processed more than once even though it does get touched and the setJSONAsTouched() method is called correctly. While I am not sure it looks like I need to find a way for forkJoin to finish before the method resolves.

Comment: forkjoin are used with array of streams, why you process array with it

Comment: Why are you using RxJS in this instance? Is there a server call somewhere in here?